# Ansible forks set to 1 for only one specific role

Tags: variables, ansible, conditional-statements

I am trying to execute 3 to 4 roles in ansible, parllel all at a time, but I want only one specific role to have **forks** option set to 1 whereas the other roles can have any number of forks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your exact end goal is but I suspect the serial directive is what you're looking for to limit how the execution operates. Keep in mind you may have to split into multiple plays within the playbook depending on how you have things setup now.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_delegation.html#rolling-update-batch-size